# Need advice on installing an application silently with patches

Tags: windows-installer

What I want to do is install program X with patches silently. Program X has an installer that is an MSI package. Program X has quite a few MSP file patches (8+)that have been released that I also want to install silently. There are two ways that I've seen to approach this:

**Method 1:** Slip Streaming into "Network" installation

```
msiexec.exe /a "C:\ProgramX\ProgramX.msi"
```

When the GUI pops up, I choose a location to extract to, then after extraction apply each patch with:

```
msiexec.exe /a "C:\admin_install_location\ProgramX.msi" /p "C:\patches\update1.msp"
```

This method takes a long time to slip stream each patch and if possible I'd like to automate it somehow, perhaps using a /qb.

**Method 2:** Apply during installation

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\ProgramX\ProgramX.msi" ADDLOCAL=ALL SOFTWARE_CLASS=Editor SEAT_PREFERENCE=Fixed /qb PATCH="C:\patches\update1.msp;C:\patches\update2.msp;C:\patches\update3.msp"
```

What I would like to get advice on is:

1. Which one is better suited for patches? Should I just slip stream for big service packs which are released less frequently and use method 2 for patches?
2. Will the slip streamed "network" install version install faster than method 2 (assume the patch list is > 8 msp files)?
3. Can I create the network location silently somehow with something like this?

   msiexec.exe /a "C:\ProgramX\ProgramX.msi" /qb INSTALLDIR="C:\admin_install_location"
4. Is there any way to apply the patches as I create the network install location such as this?

   msiexec.exe /a "C:\ProgramX\ProgramX.msi" PATCH="C:\patches\update1.msp;C:\patches\update2.msp;C:\patches\update3.msp"

Comment: Well I've figured out my #3 question:   msiexec.exe /a "C:\ProgramX\ProgramX.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\ProgramX_Admin_Install" /qb . The "TARGETDIR" public property is the special sauce.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid Method #1 due to:

[Rule 44: Avoid Patching Aministrative Installs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/06/27/648447.aspx)

Comment: That's a nice reference article! I'm also a setup author (InstallShield) and it's nice to have a best practice document from the Windows Installer team, thanks!